# Payment fails after 3d validation and redirects to checkout page paymentsense_payments module magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am using Paymentsense_Payments magento extension to integrate card payment method in a client's website. When I try to make payment it redirects to checkout page, when I checked the paymentsense log I saw this message "

> Cancel Action with message "A 3-D Secure authentication error occurred
> while processing the order" has been triggered

".
[image: Payment page]

After submit, redirects to checkout page

Comment: Can we use the Default PayPal module for 3D secure transaction in Magento 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating Paymentsense_payments plugin to the latest version, the issue was fixed